# How to pass an array to drupal7 form select as value of #options?

Tags: forms

This problem makes my head burn all day. Please see the code below.
I got a variable $region_value contains the region value with the same structure listed in the code. However different page has a different region value, so I have to use a variable to store it, it's not static.

```
$region_value = array(0 => 'US', 1 => 'EU')
//form code details have been left out.
//the below code define the form.
$form['region_options'] = array(
                '#type' => 'select',
                'prefix' => 'Region',
                '#options' => $region_value,
                               );
```

now I get the problem, cuz drupal can't accept the value of $region_value, something wrong happened cuz the $region_value's can not be passed into the form function itself in template files, it might be caused by the drupal core settings. I know it's not a good choice to write functions or other customer variables in the template files, but it's convenient for simple test, you don't have to dump the cash.

So my problem is, is there a mean to pass a variable value into the form function?

```
//variable set here
$options = array('foo' => 'bar',...)
//form define function goes here
function region_form($form, &$form_state) {
            $form['submit'] = array(
                                   '#type' => 'select',
                                   '#options' => $options,
                                   );
            return $form;
          }
```

Much appreciated for all advises.

Comment: Can you please explain how you are getting $region_value in variable_get or any other way?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [Form API docs for select lists](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select). `#options` is the correct property to set the options, and `#default_value` is used to set a default value.

Using `#value` means the user input will be ignored, and whatever you've set as `#value` will wind up being the submitted value. Since you're declaring a non-multiple select list, that value needs to be an integer (not an array) anyway.

Try something like this:

```
$region_value = array(0 => 'US', 1 => 'EU');
$form['region_options'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#prefix' => 'Region',
  '#options' => $region_value,
  '#default_value' => 0, // e.g. Set US as default selected value (appropriate array key from $region_value)
);
```

Comment: however I just found my problem was not the #options value array structure, it's how to pass a variable as the value of #options, the variable was set out of the function which define the form.

Answer (score 0):

after a dig on drupal's document, I found the solution myself, if some one got the same problem like me, please check the drupal's page

[drupal form generatation guild](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7)

at the bottom of this page you will find how to pass additional arguments into the form function.

Gold luck.